# How to keep the premium users state synced in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, local-storage

In my react app, I currently save into localstorage user as a jwt token upon logging in.

On page load, my app checks to see if I have the user in localstorage and if so I set state to be authenticated. This way, I don't have to make an api call everytime my page loads.

However, now my user has a user.isPremium attribute that checks what feature of the app the user has access to. Is it good practice to also store premium status in localstorage? This might become an issue if premium status ever changes for the user.

Or would it better to make an api call to grab user and premium status whenever page loads?

Comment: That would be a lot of API calls.  Use component state or a state container like Redux to store stuff like this instead of localStorage.

Comment: I'd say, make an API call with the token. Anything saved in the localStorage should be considered outdated and kind of a last resort convenience feature.

Comment: @jmargolisvt localStorage and state/redux solve completely different problems.

Comment: Without a doubt: you should perform an AJAX request every time your app loads, and not rely on localstorage user object. This way you make sure that the user object is synced with whatever you have in your database, and you can also "force" a logout on the user(the API call just sends the token, and get's the user object back). Imagine also that the user might be  in an "inactive" state in your DB, but the token is still valid.

Answer (score 2):

I would say if you want your app to be more flexible, make your React Routes flexible to any request "Logged in requests" and let the Back-End "API Calls" decide if the page or the feature is accessible by the user.

That way if you changed the user to `isPremium=False` from anywhere rather than your Front-End session an API call to a premium feature will fail with `HTTP Status Code: 403`, and it's your Front-End decision to log out the user or keep the user and alert the not allowed changes.

### Scenario 0

The user makes a request to `/PremiumFeatureList` the backend will response with `HTTP Status Code: 200`, the user `isPremium=True` and has the ability to request the feature.

### Scenario 1

For example to change `isPremium` to `False`:

Overdue subscription will result in `isPremium=False`, The change will be automatically applied to the back-end

### Scenario 2

The user makes a request to `/PremiumFeatureList` the Back-End will response with `HTTP Status Code: 403`, the user `isPremium=False` and doesn't have the ability to request the feature.

Comment: No need to leave "update" comments in the answer itself since Stack Overflow offers a [change history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59689104/revisions).